# In Laravel, How to specify a default value to return if the 'timezone' configuration option does not exist?

Tags: php, laravel, timezone

In Laravel 4.2 docs, "Accessing A Configuration Value" Section, [they say](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#introduction):

> You may also specify a default value to return if the configuration option does not exist:
>
> `$timezone = Config::get('app.timezone', 'UTC');`

But when I tested that, I found that if `timezone` option doesn't exist in `app.php` configuration file, then an error saying: `Undefined index: timezone` will raise, and also even if `timezone` option exists but doesn't being set with a proper timezone value (like: `UTC` or `Europe/Paris` for example), then that code will also raise an error saying: `date_default_timezone_set(): Timezone ID 'wrong_timezone_value_here' is invalid`

So, what is wrong with `timezone` configuration option?! And is there any other configuration options in Laravel that behave like `timezone` option?!

Comment: have you called it exactly like its written there?

Comment: Yes, exactly like its written there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 4.x does not use the normal Config code to set the default timezone, it calls the array directly. You can see this code in

[vendor/Laravel/Framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php#L167)

```
$config = $app['config']['app'];

date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);
```

So any value needs to be set directly in the config, and the item MUST be present. Additionally it can't be changed at runtime directly, or rather you can change the value but it won't call `date_default_timezone_set` - you'll need to do that your self.